# How can I make water flow into a 1-block gap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have some water blocks (the first line of blocks are directly placed water-sources while the others are flowing water) and I want the water to flow into an empty space, but it's not:

`s` - water source
`f` - flowing water
`d` - block
`e` - empty

```
sssss
fffff
fffff
ddedd
```

Is possible to flow the water in the empty block?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your situation/requirements. Could you update your diagram to show water source/flowing blocks. If the `w`s in your diagram are all source blocks then `e` should have water flowing into it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your diagram correctly, but keep in mind water only flows so far from a source block.  You may just be trying to go a little too far.

Comment: Perhaps a picture? As long as it isn't too far away, it should flow into the block, as long as there's nothing there. Maybe try placing a block on the flowing water blocks and removing them? This should change the source block into a flow and change the empty block.

Comment: A screenshot would greatly help clarify this problem. If you have exactly what is depicted, I would expect the water to flow to `e` (though the flows at the bottom corners may be mostly against the wall).

Comment: Also, just to check - this is all on a flat surface, right? Nothing in your diagram is 2 deep?

Answer (score 4):

I *think* I understand what you want.

If the water is not flowing into `e`, pick up all your `s` source blocks so that there is no water left, then place them again as they were before. This should reset the water flows and the water should flow into `e`.

Comment: Yeah, after the edit this makes a little more sense - I think the problem is that you placed the water and THEN added/removed blocks, which can make it act awfully strange sometimes.  This should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wide water flow like what you are showing the most common method is to have them all flow over into a collecting trench that runs along the base of them effectively turning all the D's in the same row as the E into E's.

`s` - water source
`f` - flowing water
`d` - block
`e` - empty

```
sssss
fffff
fffff
<----s
```

The diagram unfortunately starts to get a little too complicated for me to do in ASCII, hehe. Basically the water flows from the sources to a trench that is one block lower so items fall into it, then the trench floats things down it. You generally use something like signs to make it so the water from above does not flow down into the trench as well.

The problem is, if the water in minecraft feels it should flow into a solid wall, it will, making dead zones in your flow where the current can not carry things. The latest flow I have had ended up using Corner source locations to get the water to all flow into a single hole at the center of a circle. Not sure if that design could work for you if you really need that single block area for flow reasons.